# How to make a pdf link non-downloadable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

My question is that I have a pdf link coming from backend and that is set on an anchor tag.
The URL is something like this::

https://www.datocms-assets.com/24091/1601457332-andrey-fact-sheet-h9-12345.pdf

When I open this URL in an anchor link then its like a normal pdf file with a download option appearing on that.

How can I disable the download link from this PDF ?
I want all the functionality same as normal except the download link.

Regards,
Arjun Sah

Comment: Not easily achievable, and anything you implement would be pretty easy to overcome manually, eg with print screen. Fundamentally, if the data has been downloaded to the client, the client already has all the data needed to render it - and it's their computer, not yours. Only way to keep others from saving it would be to not send it in the first place.

Comment: You can't; you have no control over how the browser displays a PDF. And if your document contains a direct link to a PDF, you would also have to disable right-clicking it and selecting "save link target", or copying the link, or getting it from the source code, etc etc

Comment: If there is a way to do it, it's probably browser-specific. But I doubt it's possible. What are you trying to accomplish by removing the download link?

Comment: Also consider that Chrome on Android downloads PDFs automatically when you open them rather than showing then in the browser.

Comment: I am not sure whether it answers my question. I am checking it. I will accept your answer if it satisfies my condition.